# Matlab positioning windows at a 50% overlap

Tags: matlab, math

I am using the following code for windowing data and finding the mean of each window. The currently is used for starting each new window directly at the end of the previous window. How is this code modified so that each new window starts at a 50% overlap to the prior window.

```
 Fq = 51.2; //Sample Rate of accelerometer 
 windowLength = 5; //Length for each window in seconds
 startPos = 1; //Starting Position for 1st win

 endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq)); //End Position for 1st win
 totalWindows = floor(length(walk)/Fq/windowLength);

 stats = zeros(windowLength,9);

 for i = 1:totalWindows
     epMean = mean(walk(startPos:endPos,:)); //calculate window mean

     //X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
     walkfeature(i,1:4) = epMean; 

     //Next window position
     startPos = endPos+1;
     endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq))
 end
```

Comment: Edit the line `startPos = endPos+1;` (and obviously the definition of `totalWindows` needs to change).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very optimized but that's close to your original code and it would allow you to specify any desired overlap :

```
windowLengthInPoint = windowLength * floor(Fq) ; %// store this value

overlap = 0.2 ;  %// in portion of windowLength - 20% in this example
increment = floor(windowLengthInPoint*overlap) ;

startPos = 1 ;
endPos = startPos + windowLengthInPoint ;
Lvec = length(walk) ;
while endPos <= Lvec
    epMean = mean(walk(startPos:endPos,:)); %//calculate window mean

     %// your other code
     %// ...

    startPos = startPos + increment ;
    endPos = startPos + windowLengthInPoint ;
end
```